# When to use reference member?

Tags: c++, reference, member

I just realized I couldn't even figure out one use case of reference member in C++. Say, if I define the following class:

```
class Book {
   public:
       Book(const Author& author) : author(author) {}
   private:
       const Author &author;
}
```

How could I even use it? If I pass a `new`ed `Author` to it:

```
Book book(*(new Author()));
```

Doesn't it leak memory? When will the `Author` be released?

Let me try again. How about passing a local variable to it:

```
Book macBook() {
    Author author();
    return Book(author);
}
```

Doesn't the returned Book have a invalid(released) reference?

I can't imagine the third way to use it. So why does reference member exist? When should I use it?

**EDIT**: I know there is `share_ptr`. But should I ALWAYS prefer `share_ptr` to reference?

Comment: You can init a reference to an object, no matter how it is allocated, as long as it is guaranteed that it will outlive the reference, i.e. the instance of the object holding the reference.

Answer (score 3):

You must make sure that the author's lifetime is at least as long as the book (or, at least, be very careful not to use the book's reference outside the author's lifetime). A simple way to ensure that is to put them in the same scope, with the author created first:

```
Author author;
Book book(author);
```

As you say, both the examples in the question are bad: the first leaks memory (or would, if you added a `*` to make it compile), and the second leaves you with a dangling reference. But there are plenty of other ways to manage object lifetimes.

Answer (score 3):

If your function requires a `const Author&` and you pass a `new Author()`, then your program will not compile, because `new Author()` is an `Author*`, not an `Author&`.

You can pass a `*(new Author())`, but then you will have a leak unless the destructor of the `Book` deletes the `&author`. However, it's very odd to have a reference member and in the destructor take the address of that member and `delete` it. Your fellow developers will hate you for that, especially since it is not clear from the function signature, that the argument must to be allocated using `new`.

You can pass an `Author` to `Book(const Author& author)`, but you have to make sure that the `Author` lives at least as long as the `Book`. So yes, in the code

```
Book macBook() {
    Author author();
    return Book(author);
}
```

the returned book has an invalid reference.

I suspect reference members exist for the same reason that null pointers exist: because it was so easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

References in general are useful if copying an object by value is expensive. If you pass an object to a function as its argument and it is expensive to copy it, you will want to use a reference. Naturally, if you do not mean to have the object modifiable by the function, you'll actually use a *constant* reference:

```
void someFunc(const BigObject& object)
{
    /* 'object' is used here */
}
```

Now a class constructor is "just another function", so we can use the same pattern here: if you want to provide an object that's expensive to copy to some class instance for its use **during its lifetime**, it is meaningful to define a const-ref member in that class that will be bound to the provided object in the class constructor:

```
class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(const BigObject& object) : m_object(object) { /* ... */ }
    // ...
private:
    const BigObject& m_object;
}

BigObject object;
Worker worker(object);
```

Naturally, the most important thing to keep in mind here is to make sure the `BigObject` object **does not get destroyed** while the `Worker` object exists. (In the example above this is OK because both variables are automatic.)

Surely, a pointer could be used instead of a reference to achieve the same effect, but with pointers one always has to think of a case when the pointer is zero (intentionally or accidentally) and there's the need to explicitly use the `&` operator in passing the object, so the reference version just makes the code simpler.